# How to list tuple that contain specific string?

Tags: string, apache-pig, match

```
Input:
Visit ID             Events
101                154,2,135
124                1, 120, 1050,2302
139                200, 150, 1, 320
140                30023, 200
```

Newbie to Pig. Would like to know how to list visitID rows that contain "1" in the events using Pig script.

Thanks!

Code I tried:

```
a = LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHit/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t');  
b= foreach a GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($2, '(.*,1,.*|1,.*|.*,1)') as post_event_list;
c= FILTER b BY $0 is not NULL;
d= DISTINCT c;
dump d;
```

This prints only the event column where row contains "1". If I generate with visitID, I am getting incorrect results. I would like to print visitID along with events that contain "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write a `python udf` and see if the character in question exists in the string; might make things a lot simpler.

**python udf**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("flg:int")
def tuple_contains(tup, val):
    try:
        if val in tup:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except:
        return 0
```

**script**:

```
REGISTER /path/to/jars/tuple_contains.py USING jython AS udf;

data = LOAD 'data' AS (visit_id:chararray, event_list:chararray);
A = FILTER data BY udf.tuple_contains(STRSPLIT(event_list, ','), '1') == 1;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE visit_id, event_list;  -- ... other columns
DUMP B;
```

**output**:

```
124    1,120,1050,2302
139    200,150,1,320
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. May not be efficient way of coding but got the output accurately.

```
a = LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHit/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t');  
b= FILTER a BY $283 == '0';  
c= FILTER b BY $298 != '5' AND $298 != '8' AND $298 != '7' AND $298 != '9';
d= FOREACH c GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT($780,$781),$942),$948) as (visitID:bytearray), $614 as post_event_list, $656 as post_product_list;
e= FILTER d BY post_event_list != ' ' OR post_event_list != '' OR post_event_list is not NULL;
f= FOREACH e GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(post_event_list, '(.*,1,.*|1,.*|.*,1)') as purchase_event, visitID, post_product_list;
g= FILTER f BY $0 is not NULL;
h= dump g;
```